# Any python client method available to get/set env variables of kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-python-client

1. Need to get/set the env variables of deployment by using python client methods.
2. kubectl describe deploy command or client.read_namespaced_deployment() method doesn't return the env of container in the pods which belongs to deployment.

Can able to get/set the env using kubectl command in cli.
Kubectl command to get the env variable:

```
[user101@centoshost ~]$ kubectl --v=6 exec deploy/hello-deploy -- printenv
I0810 17:03:32.582676 3630345 loader.go:374] Config loaded from file:  /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
I0810 17:03:32.604084 3630345 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://**.***.**.***:6443/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments/hello-deploy 200 OK in 11 milliseconds
I0810 17:03:32.611606 3630345 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://**.***.**.***:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dhello-world 200 OK in 5 milliseconds
I0810 17:03:32.614546 3630345 podcmd.go:88] Defaulting container name to hello-pod
I0810 17:03:32.642551 3630345 round_trippers.go:553] POST https://**.***.**.***:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/hello-deploy-7b4cf6b899-5wkgn/exec?command=printenv&container=hello-pod&stderr=true&stdout=true 101 Switching Protocols in 27 milliseconds
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=hello-deploy-7b4cf6b899-5wkgn
NODE_VERSION=19.4.0
YARN_VERSION=1.22.19
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://100.96.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://100.96.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=100.96.0.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=100.96.0.1
HOME=/root
```

Kubectl set command to update the env variable:
`kubectl set env deploy/hello-deploy NEW_ENV_VAR="None"`

In same way need python client method to perform the get/set operations for kuberenetes deployment.

Comment: How about `import subprocess` and then `subprocess.run(["kubectl set env deploy/hello-deploy NEW_ENV_VAR="None""])`? (schematically, you need to play around with the quotes a bit for it to work)

Comment: A standard [Kubernetes client library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) should be able to do that.  Consider whether a deploy-time tool like Kustomize or Helm would be a more reproducible path than making imperative changes post-deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Kubernets offical python libaray](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python).

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
api_client = client.AppsV1Api()
name = "dep_name"
namespace = "ns"
deploy_data = api_client.read_namespaced_deployment(name=name, namespace=namespace)

# get envs from deployment's first container
dep_envs = deploy_data.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env

# set envs for deployment's first container
envs =  [client.V1EnvVar(name="var", value="vv"), client.V1EnvVar(name="var2", value="vv2")]
deploy_data.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env = envs
api_client.patch_namespaced_deployment(name, namespace, deploy_data)
```

Comment: Your answer worked as expected - Thanks, @HALF9000